# What's a `WIP` on a stash commit?

Tags: git, git-commit, git-stash

What's a `WIP` means on a stash commit?

```
$ git stash list
stash@{0}: WIP on master: 049d078 added the index file
stash@{1}: WIP on master: c264051 Revert "added file_size"
stash@{2}: WIP on master: 21d80a5 added number to log
```

I'm just curious.

Comment: WIP usually stands for "work in progress" .

Answer (score 51, accepted):

From the [`git-stash` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash):

> A stash is by default listed as "WIP on branchname …​", but you can
>   give a more descriptive message on the command line when you create
>   one.

WIP stands for ***w**ork **i**n **p**rogress*.